# boost version problem

Tags: boost, ubuntu-oneiric, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10, for which the default Boost version is 1.46. However, ROS seems to still depend on 1.42; if I want to install 1.46, it first wants to uninstall 1.42, but I can't uninstall 1.42 without uninstalling all of ROS. /opt/ros/electric/ros/rosdep.yaml lists a dependency on libboost1.46-all-dev for oneiric, though, which means rosmake refuses to build anything because of the unmet dependency.

Should I change rosdep.yaml to have libboost1.42-all-dev instead, or is there a better solution? Also, should I submit a bug report somewhere, or is this a problem only for me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12670/boost-version-problem/) by [tmullins](https://answers.ros.org/users/1294/tmullins/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think your system is in a weird state because you have the natty versions of the ROS packages installed on an oneiric system.

I would start with 'apt-get dist-upgrade'

If that doesn't work, install libboost1.46-all-dev, allow it to remove ROS, and then you should be able to reinstall ROS and keep the newer version of boost.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tmullins](https://answers.ros.org/users/1294/tmullins/) on 2012-01-22**:
It looks like that (and Rohling's comment) worked, thanks! It was too bad I had to reinstall ROS, since that takes forever... but it works with no problems now.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In addition to ahendrix's post:
Ubuntu disables all third-party repositories during a system upgrade, so the ROS packages will not upgrade at all until you fix the `deb` entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list` (un-comment if necessary and replace `natty` with `oneiric`).

---

Originally posted by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) with karma: 1951 on 2012-01-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4